# Google Maps Javascript API Ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, referrer

I am trying to render google maps on my app and it keeps saying:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
```

I know it's because I don't have a website host, but I don't really have it because it's an Android App. I don't have any hosts. I also tried without restrictions and google maps sdk with debug keystore.
Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
packages.json
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.6.2",

config.xml
<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="API_KEY" />

index.html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>

page.ts
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  LatLng,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker,
  Environment
} from "@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx";

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quem-somos',
  templateUrl: './quem-somos.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quem-somos.page.scss'],
})
export class QuemSomosPage {
  @ViewChild('map', {static: false}) mapElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('map2', {static: false}) mapElement2: ElementRef;

  map;
  map2;
  toastController;
  latLng;
  latLng2;

  constructor(toastController: ToastController, public platform: Platform, public launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator) {
      this.toastController = toastController;
   }

   ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });

   }

  loadMap(){
    Environment.setEnv({
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': 'API_KEY',
      'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': 'API_KEY'
    });

    this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.918978, -47.071869);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: this.latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    this.latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.979192, -47.127404);

    let mapOptions2 = {
      center: this.latLng2,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map2 = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement2.nativeElement, mapOptions2);

    this.addMarker();
    this.addMarker2();
  }

page.html
<div class="abrir-mapa">
        <div class="abrir-mapa" #map id="map"></div>
      </div>

page.scss
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#map2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.abrir-mapa {
    height: 25rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your implementation code, I'm assuming it's a ionic app right?

Comment: Share you code. and Also share your plugin details you are using for google maps. also are you using Google map API key?

Comment: edit: updated the post with my code

Comment: @QuethzelDíaz yes its ionic app

Comment: @NajamUSSaqib yes I am using google maps api

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem!
I just did removed android platform and deleted node_modules and it worked again!
But I guess that's not supposed to happen.